# Stargazer organize summary statistics by group (r)

Tags: r, stargazer

When stargazer is passed a data.table object, it produces beautiful summary statistic tables, organized with each variable as one row, and each statistic as a column.

```
Statistic  N  Mean  SD
Var1      10  25    2
Var2      15  35    4
```

Is there a way to get the output so that each column is a different subset of the data.table, and each variable takes three rows: one for N, mean, and SD?

```
Stat         Subset 1   Subset 2

Var1:N         5         15
Var1:mean      15        17
Var1:SD        12        35

Var2:N         13        14
Var2:Mean      10        2
Var2:SD        3         1
```